# Transmission Line (shielded dual stripline )

Tags: transmission-line, electromagnetic

Evaluate and illustrate: 
equipotential contours and a vector electric field distribution for [image: Task].
I got this result:[image: Field Distribution] and [image: Equipotential contour].
I want to ask that, is the direction of the Electric field lines are correct?

Comment: What electric field lines? The only lines I see on the graph are node number lines, label your axis correctly.

Answer (score 0):

It's a little hard to see the direction arrows on your plot, and you haven't explicitly stated what applied potential is on the center strips.

So I'm guessing, but it looks like both strips have 1V applied, the outer shield is grounded (0V), and the arrows are pointing into the strips.  If that is true, then the field lines are not pointing in the correct direction.

The electric field in the transverse plane still obeys $$ E=-\nabla \phi ,$$ so the field should point generally from the high-potential strip lines to the outer ground shield when the strip lines have a positive potential applied.

Comment: Thanks, JP and your guess are correct, the electric field lines are pointing inwards, means towards the strip. So, can you please suggest me some corrections what I should do. It would be a great help.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't know your software package.  It looks to me like the arrows are plotting the force on a negative charge (eg for an electron.)  I would start by looking at how you generated the vector plot and make sure the sign is correct.

Comment: Dear JP, I did the required changes and I got the correct plot. Thanks